# How to pass a string to a asp.net web service using jQuery/JSON/AJAX

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, json

As it is now I create a JavaScript object and then stringify it, put it in a hidden textbox and my code behind can read this string. I then use JSON.NET to parse the string which works fine. I now try to use ajax to post it to my web service but have some issues with how to send the string. I have tried many ways but gets the common errors like

```
Invalid JSON primitive: myString.
```

So I checked this out http://encosia.com/2010/05/31/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/ and it works with hard coded values but I want to use a variable.

JavaScsript to create the object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = results.rows.item(i);
    var customer = new Object();

        customer.id = row['id']
        customer.name = row['name']

    var customerString = JSON.stringify(customer);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "synchronise.asmx/synchroniseCustomers",
        data: "synchroniseCustomers: " + customerString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("An error occurred: " + status);
            },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

WebMethod:

```
 public void synchroniseCustomers(string customerString)
        {
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(customerString);
            string id = (string)o["id"];
            string name = (string)o["name"];
```

If I use  `data: '{ FirstName: "Dave", LastName: "Ward" }'`
in the example above it works but I wish to pass on a string instead.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, but you'd need to send that like this:

```
data: '{"synchroniseCustomers": ' + customerString + '}'
```

Also, there's no need to accept it as a string and manually deserialize the JSON on the .NET side.  .NET will handle all of that automatically if you declare the input type as a matching server-side structure.

This should help with what you're trying to do there: http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: Hi Dave, with data: '{"synchroniseCustomers": ' + customerString + '}'
I still get the same error, I tried to do "synchroniseCustomers:" (change place of the colon) but then got the error Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected.

Comment: I had a look at that article yesterday and didn't get it to work but I did now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your data parameter needs to be enclosed in {} if you're passing json and your webmethod needs to be visible to script by adding a decorator.  Take a look at [this blog entry](http://blog.sightsource.net/post/2009/11/15/jquery-Ajax.aspx) I wrote a while back - it has an example.  I also found [this article](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) helpful.

The attribute you should add to your asmx class is `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` and you will need to add `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]` to your webmethod if you haven't already.

...btw you *are* passing a string; it's just in json format.  If you want to use a parameter passing mechanism other than json you can leave `contentType` off your call and pass your parameters like below although you'll have to verify that your asmx will parse the parameters ok (MVC has no qualms with it :)

```
data:"FirstName=David&LastName=Ward"
```

Comment: yeah as I wrote it works with hard coded values but I'm trying to post a string instead.

Comment: things is I have about 50 variables so it's easier to stringify them and then parse it in the web service instead of having to update fields (if I need to that is) in many places.

Comment: in that case look into the jquery serialize() method to serialize your form and send it all [http://api.jquery.com/serialize/]